# URL gets cut after the hashtag

Tags: java, angular, tomcat, redirect, hashtag

Im using Java (Maven), Angular(8.3.20) and a Tomcat server

In the Java I have a sendRedirect for a HttpServletResponse with a URL that contains a hashtag.

So for example: https://localhost:4200/api/hello#world.

But the string after the # (the world part) will not appear in the frontend.

In the console/network as a header, I received https://localhost:4200/api/hello. So the #world is gone.

I have tried to change the hashtag to an encoded value (it will return a %23) but that does not work as well.

How can I get the part after the hashtag being send to the frontend? So from the backend (a url with a pound/hashtag) to the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for this problem, the solution I found is to code # to %23,
but it seems that it does not work for all browsers (ex: IE, Safari) so try to use google-chrome for example.

more information on:
https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/190941?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

#### Routing strategy

What angular *exploits* with the `HashLocationStrategy` is the fact that **any content after the `#` symbol isn't send to a server** - which makes it ideal to use it for storing application state.

#### Why is it useful

With hash routes a page reload (or revisit through bookmark) on a subpage like

`http://localhost:4200/#/articles/35`

doesn't query the server for the subpage, but instead returns the main application page.

`http://localhost:4200/`

This way the server implementation only needs to know about the root page (which is the only thing that'll ever be queried)

Using the `PathLocationStrategy` (default) the server needs to be set up to handle requests for every single URL your application implements.

So what can you do is : disable `HashLocationStrategy` in angular from routes file. Or you can append the url without # and then send it to server and handle the url on sever side.

I had the same problem, what I did was add the part which is infront of # as a query parameter, so that server can access it.
E.g. 
(`Https://localhost:4200/api/test?remainingDataFromHash=requiredData`) like this

Comment: My problem is that i have to send the url with the # in it, from the backend to the frontend. In the frontend the part from the hashtag is being cut off..

Comment: From where you are passing url to backend then?

Comment: From the frontend but when i do that, it doenst contain a hashtag. The hashtag is only been created from the backend to the frontend

Comment: It shouldnt be the case, Actually a method httpRequest.getRequestURL() in java retrieves url before #. You must be sending url from frontend with # only. Can you please once cross-confirm. I am sure because I have gone through exact same problem.

Comment: I dont use the httpRequest.getRequestURL() method. Its being passed by the @ Context HttpServletRequest request, @ Context HttpServletResponse response in java. So it is possible to post on that specific @ Path, create a url with a # in it and return a redirectURL